# removing a specific element in a list multiple times not case sensitive

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have been writing this code and researching ways to recursively run through a function and get it to return a list with the word "the" eliminated.

I am new to Common Lisp and I have been introduced to basic functions such as `setq, cons, cond, equal, car` and `cdr`.

When I run through the code, I keep getting the last element in the list and if there is a `the` after it, it follows.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and lead me in the right direction?

The allowed Common Lisp constructs are: `COND`, `EQUAL` (or `EQUALP`), `CONS`, `CAR` and `CDR`, and some basic primitive building blocks of Common Lisp.

I can not use any predefined functions to do the actual elimination.

This is what it should look like..
Sample Run:

```
(filter-out-the   '(There are the boy and THE girl and The Rose))
```

Returns:

```
(THERE ARE BOY AND GIRL AND ROSE)
```

This is my code:

```
(defun list_member (x L)
  (cond ((null L) nil)                      
        ((equal x (car L))                 
         (list_member x (cdr L)))           
        (T (cons (car l) (list_member x (cdr L))))))  


(defun filter-out-the (L)
  (setq x '(the))
  (cond ((null L) nil)                             
        ((list_member (car x) (cdr L )) (filter-out-the (cdr L))) 
        (T (cons (car L) (filter-out-the (cdr L))))))
```

Comment: The language is called *Common Lisp*, not *CLISP*.

Comment: To program in Lisp, you are required to indent your code. The editor should help you with that. Please don't post code which is not indented.

Comment: The variable `x` in `filter-out-the` is undefined. You need to define it...

Comment: Can you explain what `list_member` should do? If yes, explain it. Did you test it? How?

Comment: I am assuming I should use `(let ((x the))`

Comment: something like that, maybe quoting the `the`.

Comment: when it matches, how do I make it skip and not add?

Comment: what is the function `list_member` supposed to do? Don't comment the code. Explain what is the input and what is the output. What is the purpose of this function?

Comment: I may be approaching this wrong. I've looked at a bunch of examples that delete different ways and I thought this would work. But I keep getting the end of the list.

Comment: `list_member` is supposed to match the word "the" through the list and if it finds a match it deletes it. Common lisp is also not case sensitive so it should return any version of "the".

Comment: That can't be. There is no *word* `the` in `lisp_member`.

Comment: Okay, I see that. The variable x does not pass the word The through to `list_member`.

Comment: Why would you call a function which removes something `list_member`?

Comment: Now that the function already removes an element from a list, what purpose has the second function?

Comment: I did not realize that the both functions were doing a remove.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function is just your first function, with better naming:

```
(defun my-remove (item list)
  (cond ((null list) nil)                      
        ((equal item (first list))                 
         (my-remove item (rest list)))           
        (T (cons (first list)
                 (my-remove item (rest list))))))
```

You can just call it:

```
CL-USER 36 > (my-remove 'the '(there are the boy and the girl and the rose))
(THERE ARE BOY AND GIRL AND ROSE)
```

Comment: I find it easier to do it this way with having `my-remove` have two parameters. How would you do it with just having one parameter and just having the function delete the word "the" only.

Comment: @triniplayaz1: you write a function (of one parameter) which calls `my-remove`.